# Random number x probability in interval [0,10]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

So lets say $x=10*rand()$, so x will be equal to a random number on the interval [0,10].
So what is the probability of $2x+1$ rounding to $5$. So one can come up with $4.5<=2x+1<5.5$. Is that right? What do I do know? Also, note that $x$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and  $10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
4.5\leq 2x+1<5.5
\implies 1.75\leq x < 2.25
$$
Since it's uniform, the desired probability is the derived interval compared to the total sample space.
$$
P(1.75\leq x < 2.25) = \frac{2.25-1.75}{10} =\frac{0.5}{10} = \boxed{0.05}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are right
Dividing by $2$ you get
$$2.25 \le x <2.75$$
This is intreval of length 0.5 and random number can be in an interval of length 10.
So probability is
$$
p = 0.5/10 = 0.05$$